# Event.observe IE9

Tags: magento, internet-explorer-9, prototypejs

While using Magento 1.9 (I think that's not very important) I've got following errors in IE9:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'observe' 
validation.js, line 98 character 35
```

This exception points to an `Event.observe` call, and there are more exceptions like that.

The prototype version is `1.7.0` and it's loading as first script (by the `script src`) in `header` element. All the errors occurs in `script`s which should be loaded/initialized after the `prototype.js`.

I'm debugging it for a few hours without results. The problem does not occur in other browsers.

Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to the latest version of Prototype, and see if that solves the issue. There was a lot of work done in IE compatibility during 1.7.3.

Comment: well, it fixed some bugs, but also produced some new, anyway, thanks!